# How to take additional columns to the main select from subquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    ACCOUNT_NUMBER 
FROM
    `dataset1.split_list` s
WHERE
    Panel = 'C2'
    AND List = '504'
    AND ACCOUNT_NUMBER NOT IN (SELECT bill_acc
                               FROM `dataset2.enroll` e 
                               WHERE code IN ('50', '103', '107')
                                 AND pmo IN ('55F', 'GG2', 'LL1', 'SS0') 
                                 AND date >= '2023-05-22')
```

I need to keep all filters and rewrite query in this way to get in main select follow columns:

```
s.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, s.Panel, s.List, e.code, e.pmo, e.date, e.status
```

I tried to rewrite my query and use left join but I got wrong result.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: could you add an input example and the desired output?

Comment: @JinoMichelAque Output: s.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, s.Panel, s.List, e.code, e.pmo, e.date, e.status

Input: tables are uploaded from different sources, sorry, I can't give you an example.

Comment: could you add your input examples about how is your data in dataset2.enroll and dataset1.split_list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the enroll table and eg so your wanted information

```
SELECT 
    s.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, s.Panel, s.List
    , e.code, e.pmo, e.date, e.status
from `dataset1.split_list` s JOIN `dataset2.enroll` e  ON s.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = e.bill_acc
where Panel = 'C2'
and List = '504'
AND ACCOUNT_NUMBER NOT IN (SELECT bill_acc
from `dataset2.enroll` e 
WHERE code IN ('50','103','107')
AND pmo IN ('55F', 'GG2', 'LL1','SS0') 
AND date >= '2023-05-22')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I tried a similar way, but I had the wrong result and for that thought that it is wrong.
However, your answer gave me an idea of what can be checked and I think that I resolve the problem.  

Thank you :)

Comment: what means wrong result?

Comment: With your query, I had 30k rows, with mine 5k.

Comment: then you need to add a row_number and sort it so that you get only the wanted results